# Single line of || character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to understand `_drawControl` function of Fabric.js javascript library, but couldn't figure it out 2 lines of this, because they don't look like functions and not conditional if, so what's the purpose here?

**Line 1:**

```
isVML() || this.transparentCorners || ctx.clearRect(left, top, size, size);
```

**Line 2:**

```
ctx[methodName + 'Rect'](left, top, size, size);
```

**Full function:**

```
_drawControl: function(control, ctx, methodName, left, top) {
  if (!this.isControlVisible(control)) {
    return;
  }
  var size = this.cornerSize, stroke = !this.transparentCorners && this.cornerStrokeColor;
  switch (this.cornerStyle) {
    case 'circle':
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(left + size / 2, top + size / 2, size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx[methodName]();
      if (stroke) {
        ctx.stroke();
      }
      break;
    default:
      isVML() || this.transparentCorners || ctx.clearRect(left, top, size, size);
      ctx[methodName + 'Rect'](left, top, size, size);
      if (stroke) {
        ctx.strokeRect(left, top, size, size);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The first two cases are obvious, if `isControlVisible` returns true, just return, otherwise... if `.cornerStyle` is not `circle` go to the default. Then the "magic" starts ... but it's really quite simple. `||` is a logical OR, so it calls the `isVML` function, if it returns true, there's no need to check the others, if it returns false it then checks `.transparentCorners`, and again if it's false it runs `ctx.clearRect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. The first short-circuits and takes the first true argument:

```js
let foo = false || "foo" || "never reached";
console.log(foo); // foo

let bar = "bar" || "never reached" || false;
console.log(bar); // bar
```

The second one calls an object's method via bracket notation (using 4 arguments) - it's used to dynamically call a method:

```js
function Foo() {
  
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    console.log('bar');
  }


let foo = new Foo();
let variable = 'bar';
foo[variable]();

// same as

foo.bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator is in this case used for [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation). It starts with executing `isVML()`, and if that returns a falsy value, it will continue to the next statement (`this.transparentCorners`) and check the same. When a truthy value is reached, then that value will be returned. In this case the return value is not used.